# Total, Quantity, Price in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a table named 'products' with 5 fields (id, title, price, quantity, total).

My goal is to calculate via the form products.create the total, price * quantity.

**Database - products**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->double('price');
            $table->double('total')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Model - product**

```
protected  $fillable = ['title', 'quantity', 'price', 'total']; 

    public function setTotalAttribute()
    {
        $this->total = $this->quantity * $this->price; 
    }

    public function getTotalAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }
```

** Controller - ProductController**

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::oldest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.products.index', compact('products'))
                  ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)-1)*5);
    }


    public function create()
    {

        $products = Product::all();
        return view('admin.products.create', compact('products'));
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'title' => 'required',
                'quantity' => 'required',
                'price' => 'required',
                'total' => 'required'


        ]);

        Product::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                    ->with('success', 'save');
    }
```

My problem is in my view "products.create" I have 3 fields when I encode the 3 fields, nothing happens ???

**Products.create**

```
<form class="panel-body" action="{{route('products.store')}}" method="POST" novalidate>
              @csrf
              <fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="form-group-input-1">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="{{ old('title')}}"/>
                {!! $errors->first('title', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('quantity') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="form-group-input-1">Quantity</label>
                <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control" value="{{ old('quantity')}}"/>
                {!! $errors->first('quantity', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('price') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="form-group-input-1">Price</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" value="{{ old('price')}}"/>
                {!! $errors->first('price', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
              </fieldset>

              <a href="{{route('products.index')}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Back</a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Valider</button>
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Where do you want to show the total? Inside `setTotalAttribute()` you should probably have `$this->attributes['total'] = $this->quantity * $this->price; `. [Defining A Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you didn't send any total value...

```
 $request->validate([
                'title' => 'required',
                'quantity' => 'required',
                'price' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Just follow Eloquent ORM

```
$product = New Product();
$product-title = $request->title;
$product-quantity = $request->quantity;
$product-price = $request->price;
$product-total = $request->price * $request* quantity;
$product->save();
```

//redirect()

Answer (score 0):

The mutator will receive the value that is being set on the attribute, so your mutator method should be like this on you `Product` model

```
public function setTotalAttribute()
{
    $this->attributes['total'] = $this->quantity * $this->price;
}
```